# How to enable/disable beep sound from cpu

Tags: 16.04, gnome, sound, pulseaudio, cpu

I know the beep sound from the CPU is to indicate whether the system is running properly or not. However, I want to be able to enable/disable it. Is there any command to enable/disable beep sound from the CPU?

I have done some research: [How do I make my PC speaker beep?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep).

This link seems to be outdated and not applicable for the latest gnome:

[How to disable beep sound]
(https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-disable-or-turn-off-beep-sound-for-terminal/)

Comment: Is it the "terminal beep" you want to disable? It's what your second link suggests and if so you can disable it in Terminal's profile preferences.

Comment: I want to disable at the start up

Comment: At startup it has nothing to do with Ubuntu or any OS for that matter. It has to do with BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Some BIOS allow disabling system beeps, or unplug the beeper from the mainboard. Consider that in case your BIOS won't boot beep codes are the **only** hint for debugging the issue.